# What hardware (CPU) in which the `rem` and `div` are two different assembly instructions?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, llvm, division, instructions

I'm researching about the optimization of `llvm IR` and I notices the pass `div-rem-pairs`.

I found the source code about this pass and this is the [link](https://llvm.org/doxygen/DivRemPairs_8cpp_source.html).

I paste the comment below.

```
       // The target does not have a single div/rem operation,
       // and the rem is *not* in a already-expanded form.
       // Decompose the remainder calculation as:
       // X % Y --> X - ((X / Y) * Y).
```

The comment mention about if the target (hardware) does NOT have the **single div/rem instruction**, do the thing below.

In my point, the **single div/rem instruction** means that the assembly instruction `div` can get the quotient and remainder in the same time.

But I don't know what hardware separates the `div` into `div` and `rem` instructions.

Comment: The question assumes the processor does have a `rem` instruction. For some processor that neither has a `rem` instruction, nor gives the remainder as a side-effect of the division, line 307 says `// X % Y --> X - ((X / Y) * Y).`

Comment: I think the point isn't that there is a separate `rem` instruction, but that `div` might not provide a remainder with some simple processor. If there is a separate `rem` instruction then the multiplication - subtraction method need not be used.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for your explanation. So, what hardware of `div` does not provide a remainder with some simple processor? Or, what keyword do I search on google to get these information?

Comment: I don't know of one, but my guess is that your source is covering all bases.

Comment: [Most RISC architectures of the ’90s, including POWER, Alpha, and PA-RISC...](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304495/why-don-t-most-risc-isas-write-integer-mulh-mul-or-div-rem-to-two-general-purpos) -- take with a grain of salt, alpha actually does not have integer division at all, pa-risc has something weird (divide step?), powerpc seems to be the right answer

Answer (score 3):

[RISC-V has separate DIV and REM instructions](https://riscv.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/riscv-spec-v2.2.pdf). But *not having a single div/rem operation* doesn't mean that there are separate DIV/REM instructions. It just means that there isn't an instruction that returns quotient and remainder at the same time. Usually architectures have only DIV if they ever support division, and remainder will also be returned by the DIV instruction if supported which means DIV returns the values in 2 registers

But most RISC architectures don't have the ability to return multiple values in an instruction because that needs a vastly bigger register file with double or more read/write ports, and makes out-of-order execution as well as register renaming harder. Therefore they mostly don't return both the quotient and the remainder at the same time like x86. If you want to get both you need to calculate the remainder with a multiplication: `X % Y = X - ((X / Y) * Y)`

Some examples on godbolt:

- [SPARC](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBJcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4ByanpAqHhUSyx8VyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BgVU1AnUNBEWRMXEJtvWNzTltwz1hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHAoExF4OANR4xJgKXrQEJhoAgiYA7FYXO/d7gjsAjib%2Bt%2BcPjwQ7xG8f1wAIv8zpcLhstrtaAcjidQdcPl9aAJgDtkUYXiC7g90ajcb8sZcrsD3vCLvtDscfvgAG4QMI/VSkb47ACec3hN1BXwpsJ%2Bf1J2PuxAAdM8dm9ATtVAB6VmEr6i4gS/xS1QSswAVjZCoeBwIywYBMFROBF1B0MpJx2tIg%2BPxTLRKKdGPZnMROJhVONHuFYpVarlur9ysl0o12vlJsVmANxCNAoBxNBHAWtE4mt4fg4WlIqE4bms1h2CiWK0wGv8PFIBE0qYWAGsQGZJCKAJyargaLgtrtcAAcbckZn0nEkWbrec4vAUIA0NbrCzgsCQaBYSTocXIlDXG/o8WQBiMXH8GnnNBOcVnEGik%2BiYQarM41bXbEEAHkGLQnzneFgWIYwDiL%2BpD4AcNQ0ock6YKo1ReAQazVgymDpiBtB4NExCPh4WCTpseAsM%2BqZ8AYwAKAAangmAAO7vkkjBETIggiGI7BSEx8hKGok66NIR7GEWlj6Bhs6QAsqBJI4AizhwAC077%2BDssnDMAsYlkkDTIDOKHVFJfgQK4ox%2BIkIRTCUZR6CkaR6UZln5HpvTmbMtg6R0DBdCMngtHo7R6R5kzFP05RDN0tmVBMjlBRICylssqx6JsmCIcRqGZqQ2a5vmHCqP2ABssm5ZIOyHoBOwniKGgVTsECFpY1jMrghAkJWiQ7B466bqGZj%2BJIcy8LWv5zAsCCYEwWDxBAjYBFcIqai2khtv4VxDm2GiaoEqHjqQhFdvOGW8FlM5zgug2kMuiAoKgHX7tuEC7p1KD8SeZ58HQCHENet4gfezDED%2BL5XW%2BBCft%2Bk7/oBwG5mBul4JBMm5jBcEIYxyGobm6GYdhGBrLm%2BGEdwxFUKRFFUbR9HZtW/DMaI4jsVTnEqOoIG6CO/EoIJNgY6Jk15pJGQyfJinKQ0qk/AoGkrDSbbafYekuAw7heTkLZBArkUzPE/Z5NZGS2SrVkFAw6sWVrvm1BMevSGbnQRWZUWmxbSt%2BCrGzdMbAz9jFZbxYkiXJWmGYTiBWU5flhXFfxZX%2BBVVU1RzDX4EQXVVsy7V7nElZmH1J1aENpAjWNAw802S2zfNi3LQta0bWOQeZdOtjHQNucBxwZh1wdDfN/WpCQR9GQgJIQA)
- [PowerPC](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBJcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4ByanpAqHhUSyx8VyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BgVU1AnUNBEWRMXEJtvWNzTltwz1hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHAoExF4OANR4xJgKXrQEJhoAgiYA7FYXO/d7gjsAjib%2Bt%2BcPjwQ7xG8f1wAIv8zpcLhstrtaAcjidQdcPl9aAJgDtkUYXiC7g90ajcb8sZcrsD3vCLvtDscfvgAG4QMI/VSkb47ACec3hN1BXwpsJ%2Bf1J2PuxAAdM8dm9ATtVAB6VmEr6i4gS/xS1QSswAVjZCoeBwIywYBMFROBF1B0MpJx2tIg%2BPxTLRKKdGPZnMROJhVONHuFYpVarlur9ysl0o12vlJsVmANxCNAoBxNBHAWtE4mt4fg4WlIqE4bms1h2CiWK0wGv8PFIBE0qYWAGsQGZJCKAJyargaLgtrtcAAcbckZn0nEkWbrec4vAUIA0NbrCzgsCQaBYSTocXIlDXG/o8WQBiMXH8GnnNBOcVnEGik%2BiYQarM41bXbEEAHkGLQnzneFgWIYwDiL%2BpD4AcNQ0ock6YKo1ReAQazVgymDpiBtB4NExCPh4WCTpseAsM%2BqZ8AYwAKAAangmAAO7vkkjBETIggiGI7BSEx8hKGok66NIR7GEWlj6Bhs6QAsqBJI4AizhwAC077%2BDssnDMAsY7EkSTIAAbOOtgodUUl%2BBArijH4iQhFMJRlHoKRpIZpk2fkhm9FZsx6fYhldCMngtHo7SeRMLn9OUQzdA5lSBZZwUSAspbLKseibJgiHEahmakNmub5hwqj9lpsk6Tsh6ATsJ4iho5U7BAhaWNYzK4IQJCVokOweOum6hmY/iSHMvC1r%2BcwLAgmBMFg8QQI2ARXCKmotpIbb%2BFcQ5thomqBKhumEV286Zbw2UznOC4DaQy6ICgqDtfu24QLuHUoPxJ5nnwdAIcQ163iB97MMQP4vhdb4EJ%2B36Tv%2BgHAbmYEGXgkEybmMFwQhjHIahuboZh2EYGsub4YR3DEVQpEUVRtH0dm1b8MxojiOxFOcSo6ggboI78Sggk2GjokTXmkkZDJ8mKcpDSqT8GnIDO%2BkdEZJk%2BTk5kMOgQUzCFtkFJkMtmXkdkZIr1mVBLAVherfn67UkXFNFEWG9kGsbN0OuzLFZYJYkSUpWmGYTiB2W5flhXFRiZUVRoVU1VYQk7A1RCdVWzJtXucSVmYvVHVog2kMNo0DFzTaLTNc0LUt82retY6e1l062Id/Wp%2B7HBmGXe0V9X9akJBb0ZCAkhAA%3D)
- [ARM](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBJcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4ByanpAqHhUSyx8VyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BgVU1AnUNBEWRMXEJtvWNzTltwz1hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHAoExF4OANR4xJgKXrQEJhoAgiYA7FYXO/d7gjsAjib%2Bt%2BcPjwQ7xG8f1wAIv8zpcLhstrtaAcjidQdcPl9aAJgDtkUYXiC7g90ajcb8sZcrsD3vCLvtDscfvgAG4QMI/VSkb47ACec3hN1BXwpsJ%2Bf1J2PuxAAdM8dm9ATtVAB6VmEr6i4gS/xS1QSswAVjZCoeBwIywYBMFROBF1B0MpJx2tIg%2BPxTLRKKdGPZnMROJhVONHuFYpVarlur9ysl0o12vlJsVmANxCNAoBxNBHAWtE4mt4fg4WlIqE4bms1h2CiWK0wGv8PFIBE0qYWAGsQGZJCKAJyargaLgtrtcAAcbckZn0nEkWbrec4vAUIA0NbrCzgsCQaBYSTocXIlDXG/o8WQBiMXH8GnnNBOcVnEGik%2BiYQarM41bXbEEAHkGLQnzneFgWIYwDiL%2BpD4AcNQ0ock6YKo1ReAQazVgymDpiBtB4NExCPh4WCTpseAsM%2BqZ8AYwAKAAangmAAO7vkkjBETIggiGI7BSEx8hKGok66NIR7GEWlj6Bhs6QAsqBJI4AizhwAC077%2BDssnDMAsY7A0LAzih1RSX4ECuKMfiJCEUwlGUegpGkumGRZ%2BS6b0ZmzLY2kdAwXQjJ4LR6O0unuZMxT9OUQzdDZlQTA5gUSAspbLKseibJgiHEahmakNmub5hwqj9gAbLJOWSDsh6ATsJ4iho5U7BAhaWNYzK4IQJCVokOweOum6hmY/iSHMvC1r%2BcwLAgmBMFg8QQI2ARXCKmotpIbb%2BFcQ5thomqBKh46kIRXbzulvCZTOc4LgNpDLogKCoO1%2B7bhAu4dSg/EnmefB0AhxDXreIH3swxA/i%2Bl1vgQn7fpO/6AcBuZgTpeCQTJuYwXBCGMchqG5uhmHYRgay5vhhHcMRVCkRRVG0fR2bVvwzGiOI7GU5xKjqCBugjvxKCCTY6OiRNeaSRkMnyYpykNKpPxMA0yAIAVWn2LpLgMO4nk5MZ8sRTMQWWQUmSK0ZeRWRkqvmZULm%2BRMoXOTLtThaZkVhSF2veVbAVq1FiyxWxNYHElaYZhOIGZdleUFUV/Glf45WVdV7P1fgRCdVWzJtXucSVmYvXHVog2kMNo0DNzTaLTNc0LUt82retY6%2Bxl062Ed/UZ97HBmJX%2B3V3X9akJB70ZCAkhAA)
- [RISC-V](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBJcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4ByanpAqHhUSyx8VyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BgVU1AnUNBEWRMXEJtvWNzTltwz1hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHAoExF4OANR4xJgKXrQEJhoAgiYA7FYXO/d7gjsAjib%2Bt%2BcPjwQ7xG8f1wAIv8zpcLhstrtaAcjidQdcPl9aAJgDtkUYXiC7g90ajcb8sZcrsD3vCLvtDscfvgAG4QMI/VSkb47ACec3hN1BXwpsJ%2Bf1J2PuxAAdM8dm9ATtVAB6VmEr6i4gS/xS1QSswAVjZCoeBwIywYBMFROBF1B0MpJx2tIg%2BPxTLRKKdGPZnMROJhVONHuFYpVarlur9ysl0o12vlJsVmANxCNAoBxNBHAWtE4mt4fg4WlIqE4bms1h2CiWK0wGv8PFIBE0qYWAGsQGZJCKAJyargaLgtrtcAAcbckZn0nEkWbrec4vAUIA0NbrCzgsCQaBYSTocXIlDXG/o8WINP8ZgAtMgDEYuP4NPOaCc4rOINFJ9Ewg1WZxq2u2IIAPIMWgPxzXgsBYQxgHEYDSHwA4ahpQ5J0wVRqi8Ag1mrBlMHTKDaDwaJiHfDwsEnTY8BYT9Uz4AxgAUAA1PBMAAd1/JJGAomRBBEMR2CkDj5CUNRJ10aQL2MItLH0PDZ0gBZUCSRwBFnDgT1/fwZyw6oFL8CBXFGPxEhCKYSjKPQUjSLS9NM/ItN6YzZlsDSOgYLoRk8Fo9HaLSXMmYp%2BnKIZuksyoJlsvyJAWUtllWPRNkwdDKOwzNSGzXN8w4AAlABJIQ3BPWjfiPMxgGQHZz3AnYrxFDQqp2CBC0saxmVwQgSErRIdg8ddN1DMx/EkOZeFrYC5gWBBMCYLB4ggRsAiuEVNRbSQ238K4hzbDRNUCbDx1Iciu3nFLeDSmc5wXYbSGXRAUFQLr923CBd26kBDwANkkM9RKvG8%2BDoNDiEfZ8oNfZhiCAr8bp/Ah/0AydQPAyDcxgzS8HgpTcyQlC0PYzDsNzXD8MIjA1lzUjyO4SiqGouiGOY1js2rfhONEcReMZ/iVHUKDdBHUSUHEmx8ek6a83kjIlJUtSHPsLSXAYdw3JyAy5dCmZ/LMgpMgV/S8nMjIVZMypHK8iYgql5HOhCoywuCwKtY8y3fNV8LFiiniawOeK0wzCcoLSrKcrygq3uK0rRIq/wqpqur%2Baa/AiB6qtmU6vc4krMwBrOrQRtIMaJoGYWmxW%2BbFuW1alo2raxx91Lp1sU6hqzr2ODMaujtrhv61IeD/oyEBJCAA%3D)

You can see all of them have a `mul` instruction after `div` with slightly varying mnemonics. In case of ARM64 it's an `msub` which means multiply-subtract

Even MIPS, which is probably the oldest RISC architecture and returned both quotient and remainder in the LO and HI registers in the same DIV instruction, now [also uses a multiplication to get remainder](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBJcpAAOqAqETgwe3r4ByanpAqHhUSyx8VyJdpgOGUIETMQEWT5%2BgVU1AnUNBEWRMXEJtvWNzTltwz1hfaUDFQCUtqhexMjsHAoExF4OANR4xJgKXrQEJhoAgiYA7FYXO/d7gjsAjib%2Bt%2BcPjwQ7xG8f1wAIv8zpcLhstrtaAcjidQdcPl9aAJgDtkUYXiC7g90ajcb8sZcrsD3vCLvtDscfvgAG4QMI/VSkb47ACec3hN1BXwpsJ%2Bf1J2PuxAAdM8dm9ATtVAB6VmEr6i4gS/xS1QSswAVjZCoeBwIywYBMFROBF1B0MpJx2tIg%2BPxTLRKKdGPZnMROJhVONHuFYpVarlur9ysl0o12vlJsVmANxCNAoBxNBHAWtE4mt4fg4WlIqE4bms1h2CiWK0wGv8PFIBE0qYWAGsQGZJCKAJyargaLgtrtcAAcbckZn0nEkWbrec4vAUIA0NbrCzgsCQaBYSTocXIlDXG/o8WQBiMXH8GnnNBOcVnEGik%2BiYQarM41bXbEEAHkGLQnzneFgWIYwDiL%2BpD4AcNQ0ock6YKo1ReAQazVgymDpiBtB4NExCPh4WCTpseAsM%2BqZ8AYwAKAAangmAAO7vkkjBETIggiGI7BSEx8hKGok66NIR7GEWlj6Bhs6QAsqBJI4AizhwAC077%2BDssnDMAsY7CweBJHYM4odUUl%2BBArijH4iQhFMJRlHoKRpPpxlWfk%2Bm9BZsy2LpHQMF0IyeC0ejtPpnmTMU/TlEM3R2ZUExOcFEgLKWyyrHomyYIhxGoZmpDZrm%2BYcKo/YAGyyXlkg7IegE7CeIoaJVOwQIWljWMyuCECQlaJDsHjrpuoZmP4khzLwta/nMCwIJgTBYPEECNgEVwipqLaSG2/hXEObYaJqgSoeOpCEV286Zbw2UznOC5DaQy6ICgqCdfu24QLuXUoPxJ5nnwdAIcQ163iB97MMQP4vtdb4EJ%2B36Tv%2BgHAbmYF6XgkEybmMFwQhjHIahuboZh2EYGsub4YR3DEVQpEUVRtH0dm1b8MxojiOx1OcSo6ggboI78Sggk2JjolTXmkkZDJ8mKcpDSqT8GlaUVKE6fY%2BkuAw7jeTkpkK1FMwhdZBSZErJl5DZGRq5ZlRuf5Ezha5su1JF5nRRFYU6751tBerMWLPFbE1gcKVphmE4gdluUFUVJX8eV/iVdVtWc41%2BBEN1VbMh1e5xJWZj9adWjDaQo3jQMvNNstc0LUtK2Letm1jn7WXTrYJ2DZnPscGYVeHTX9f1qQkGfRkICSEAA%3D%3D) because modern MIPS derives from MIPSr6 which doesn't have the LO and HI registers anymore

> multiply and divide instructions redefined so that they use a single register for their result
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#MIPS32/MIPS64

AFAIK some weirder RISC architectures even have *separate DIV instructions for each division stage in the pipeline* (not separate DIV into DIV and REM instructions) to keep instruction cycles the same. But modern CPUs may have the ability to *macro-fuse* multiple instructions into one, like x86 which fuses compare and jump instructions. Some high-performance RISC CPUs also have the ability to macro-fuse and may return both the quotient and remainder in the same operation. You can find this in the [RISC-V spec](https://riscv.org/specifications/):

> If both the quotient and remainder are required from the same division, the recommended code sequence is: `DIV[U] rdq, rs1, rs2; REM[U] rdr, rs1, rs2` (*rdq* cannot be the same as *rs1* or *rs2*). Microarchitectures can then fuse these into a single divide operation instead of performing two separate divides.